# Handling a parse push notification with cordova push plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, parse-platform

I'm trying to build an app that will be available to get Push notification data and process it in angularJS scope. Pushes are coming to device and I have them displayed on tray. When I click push - app opens. But I can't recieve a data in JS.
These plugins are installed: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and https://github.com/avivais/phonegap-parse-plugin

```
parsePlugin.initialize('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', function() {
    //okay, we are registered!
    parsePlugin.getInstallationObjectId(function(data) {
        alert('Okay!');
    }, function(e) {
        alert('error');
    });
}, function(e) {
    alert('error while authenticating!');
});
```

Well, it's registering. Also I have an onNotification function there, called by PushPlugin

```
var onNotification = function(e) // This never happens :(
{
            alert("Push came!");
            angular.element(document.getElementById('pushCtrl')).scope().getMessage(e);
            angular.element(document.getElementById('pushCtrl')).scope().$apply();
};
```

And nothing happens. Typical app behavior is 'Okay!' and after push sending it gets to the device only.

Also, if I insert PushPlugin registration function, app crashes while trying to resolve regid:

```
   $cordovaPush.register({"senderID": "xxxxxxxxxx","ecb": "onNotificationGCM"}).then(function(token) {
        if(token="OK"){
            $scope.net=true; //show a net icon in the top of the screen
        }
    }, function(err) {
        $scope.token = err;
    });
}
```

What's wrong with this? Am I able to get push data to app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code is will work but i noticed one error.
for $cordovaPush.register, your "ecb" value is  "onNotificationGCM"; but earlier you declared  "onNotification" (var onNotification = function(e)..........)

change "ecb" value to "onNotification".

i hope it helps!!!!!